# Grouping records that haven't groups values

Tags: c#, linq

Please consider this records:

```
Id        Week         Value
-----------------------------
1          1           1000
2          1           1200
3          2           800
4          3           1800
5          3           1100
6          3           1000
```

I want to group records for 4 weeks but we haven't record for week 4.For Example:

```
Week         Count
---------------------
1              2
2              1
3              3
4              0
```

How I can do this with linq?

Thanks

Comment: You cant have EF and Linq2SQL. Choose one.

Comment: Build a view to do it in SQL Server for you, then use EF to query the view.

Comment: You could probably use `Enumerable.Range(1,4)` to specify the exact numbers you're after...Then do the count in SQL and the grouping in the code.

Comment: Create a collection that just holds numbers in range of 1-4 and join it with your collection that holds the data (left join that is).

Try following MSDN documentation on implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need an array of weeks then this query might help

```
    var weeks = new List<int>{1,2,3,4}

    var q = from w in weeks
        join rw in (
            from r in table
            group r by r.Week into g
            select new {week = g.Key, count = g.Count()}) on w  equals rw.week into p
        from x2 in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {w, count = (x2 != null ? x2.count : 0)};
```

> [online result in .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yKTh7p)

Comment: this does not compiles even

Comment: @Kerezo khahesh mikonam ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
            .GroupJoin(table,
                week => week,
                record => record.Week,
                (week, records) => new { Week = week, Count = records.Count() });
```

As suggested by jessehouwing, the Enumerable.Range will return the possible week numbers to be used as left outer keys within the join.

### GroupJoin will then accept as parameters

- A lambda/delegate/method that returns the left outer key
- A lambda/delegate/method that extracts the right key from your table.
- A lambda/delegate/method that builds an item of the result.

Regards,
Daniele.